# Client certificate - but only for specific route with haproxy

Tags: ssl, haproxy, client-certificates

I would client certificate only for specific paths with `HAProxy`.
For example:

`https://localhost:443/index.html`  -> no client certificate requested
`https://localhost:443/login` -> client certificate is requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't seem possible, because the SSL negotiation occurs and must be complete and successful before the path is sent by the client and can be known by the proxy.